# Seems like a bug in MVC 4 Razor "for" loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, for-loop

I am writting an MVC4 using Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 version 4.0.30.506.0 and I have a for loop inside a razor page that generates an stupid runtime error!

This is the code I wrote:

```
@{
                    if (Model.IsAuction)
                    {
                        <li class="bc49">@Html.ActionLink("ABCD", "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = "all", keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="bc49">@Html.ActionLink("EFGH", "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = "all", keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                    }

                    int crumpsCount = 48;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
                    {
                        className = "bc" + crumpsCount;

                        if (Model.IsAuction)
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(Model.Categories[i].Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = Model.Categories[i].Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(Model.Categories[i].Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = Model.Categories[i].Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }

                        crumpsCount--;
                    }
                }
```

And here is the error generated by Visual Studio 2012:

[image: Error generated!]

The error happens after the loop is finished and i's value is equal to Model.Categories.Count. Seems like the compiler tries to access the Model.Categories[Model.Categories.Count] value!

The funny fact is that, when I replace this code with foreach loop or even if I add a foreach loop right after the for loop, the code executes correctly and pass over the for loop!

This is the code that works:

```
@{
                    if (Model.IsAuction)
                    {
                        <li class="bc49">@Html.ActionLink("ABCD", "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = "all", keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <li class="bc49">@Html.ActionLink("EFGH", "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = "all", keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                    }

                    int crumpsCount = 48;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++)
                    {
                        className = "bc" + crumpsCount;

                        if (Model.IsAuction)
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(Model.Categories[i].Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = Model.Categories[i].Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(Model.Categories[i].Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = Model.Categories[i].Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }

                        crumpsCount--;
                    }

                    foreach (CategoryInfo categoryInfo in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        className = "bc" + crumpsCount;

                        if (Model.IsAuction)
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(categoryInfo.Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = categoryInfo.Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(categoryInfo.Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = categoryInfo.Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }

                        crumpsCount--;
                    }
                }
```

I just shared this code to see if this is a bug or not and if it is a bug is it a known one or not.

Thanks to everyone. :)

**Update:**
That's so stupid, now the code does not work with foreach loop either!

[image]

There are no indexing inside the foreach loop but the exception mentions that the index is out of range!

Here is the code:

```
foreach (CategoryInfo categoryInfo in Model.Categories)
                    {
                        className = "bc" + crumpsCount;

                        if (Model.IsAuction)
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(categoryInfo.Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "auction", category = categoryInfo.Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="@className">@Html.ActionLink(categoryInfo.Title, "Search", "Home", new {city = "all", type = "product", category = categoryInfo.Name, keyword = "all", condition = "all", sort = "asc"})</li>
                        }

                        crumpsCount--;
                    }
```

I should also mention that Model.Categories is a IList<> object.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: i think you have your sign the wrong way int i = 0; i < Model.Categories.Count; i++ should be int i = 0; i > Model.Categories.Count; i++

Comment: sorry ignore my comment i had code blindness :-)

Comment: Have you considered using templates instead of speechifying your views with those loops?

Comment: @SLaks: Exception message: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index" and StackTrack: "at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.SZArrayHelper.get_Item[T](Int32 index)
   at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Product_cshtml.Execute()..."

Comment: @NicholasKing: I know what you mean. ;)

Comment: what happens if you change your for loop to int i = 0; i <= Model.Categories.Count; i++

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: I changed the code to foreach and it worked but I want to trace this error to see if this is a bug or not.

Comment: Unlikely to be a bug.

Comment: That error is almost definitely actually coming from a different line.  (Probably a line involving an array)

Comment: @SLaks: Yes you are right I solved the problem. The was an array 10 lines below the place compiler shows, my database returns an empty array and there is a direct access to index 0 of the array. I didn't know what to do with this question, either delete it or answer it or just leave a comment to mention the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. There is not a bug in MVC the way I saw that but a wrong exception referencing in MVC/Razor runtime that referred to a line above the exact error location and made me think that there is a bug in the framework's runtime.
The real exception was about an array which was returned empty from database and the code I wrote was trying to access the index 0 of that array and so there was a out of range exception in my code, but the exception was referencing 10 lines higher than the exact access code I wrote so I thought that it would be a bug.
Thanks for reply comments and hope this will help someone in the future.

Comment: wow same thing happened to me (7 years later : ' ), debugger said my for loop was wrong I had to just start rolling back chnages, error was somewhere totally different, weird.